# Is it possible to add a custom search field that contains multiple values in Lucene?

Tags: lucene

According to this page:

http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/2_9_1/queryparsersyntax.html

you can do searches like

title:"The Right Way" AND text:go

I would like to add a new field "testfield" that contains multiple values like {A,B,C,E}.

So I could get one search result #1 who's "testfield" = {A,B,C,E}
another search result #2 who's "testfield" = {C,E,D,F}.

My goal is to be able to do searches like:

testfield:"C" AND testfield:"E"

In this case it should return both search results #1 and #2.

However, if I do:

testfield:"A" OR testfield:"B"

then I should only get search result #1.

How can a add a new lucene field to accomplish doing simple queries like I described above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the field several times, something like ...

```
document.Add(new Field("testfield", "A"));
document.Add(new Field("testfield", "B"));
document.Add(new Field("testfield", "C"));
```